# What' on the future roadmap for the Office JS API?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I would like to know what are the future plans for the Office JS API, in particular I am interested in the following functionality:

- inserting OOXML into Powerpoint documents
- selecting, deleting and replacing named items via API

Basically when will it be possible to fully manipulate the document via the JS API?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

The platform is evolving; we know that there are plenty of more APIs that we want to enable, and more are being added each month.  For example, you can see some of the forthcoming APIs that we're working on at http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/openspec.  You can also provide us feedback via https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

There are numerous factors that we consider for the order in which we add the APIs.  Some factors are purely practical: if there is a high-value API that we can add easily, that's a much better investment of time than trying to implement an API that's not easily exposable by the platform. Likewise -- modulo some exceptions -- we tend to prefer APIs that will work across all endpoints (Desktop, Online, Mac, iOS, etc.), over APIs that would be limited to one of those endpoints. This is not to say we wouldn't work on such APIs eventually, but it's just a matter of ordering -- and in fact, we often do get the dialog going internally, so that if another team is already planning to expose feature XYZ to some endpoint (i.e., Excel Online or iOS), we then queue it up to expose via our APIs as well.  Finally (and to some extent, most importantly!), we listen very closely to community feedback both in the form of individual questions and request on UserVoice and StackOverflow, and requests from close partners -- internal and external -- that we work with.

For your concrete questions:

- Named items in the API are something that is on our radar. When we looked into it a year ago, there were issues with exposing add or delete functionality across all endpoints, but that might no longer be an issue. We will be looking into it in the coming months. Until that time, I would recommend using `bindings` where you can, which are very similar in spirit to named ranges, except not visible to the user.
- OOXML in PowerPoint: I don't have first-hand knowledge regarding this, but I'll pass it on to the person who does.

Comment: thx for your comprehensive answer ... bindings sound interesting but don't work with Powerpoint. but anyway. thx

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up! Any chance to see Excel JS APIs newer than 1.1 in Office Online Server?

Comment: @DmytroL, it's been a couple years since I was involved in the day-to-day decisions regarding Excel APIs... so I'm not sure.  This might be a good suggestion/feedback to post on UserVoice (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft thanks - upvoted a suggestion exactly on this topic three years ago: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10885545-enable-office-add-in-javascript-to-run-on-office

Still no reply / comments from MSFT, though :( Not sure if you ever have a chance / desire to bring this into attention of someone who's involved in Office Online Server / Excel API decision making, but I'd greatly appreciate if you could.

Comment: @DmytroL, sure thing.  I just emailed one of my colleagues about it, who should be in the best position to address this...

Comment: 2 more years have passed. The UserVoice channel is no longer available. Where do we stand today? Where are we headed? Where can I see the APIs that are being worked on for the next version? Things like Shapes collection still seem a far cry in December 2021
.

Comment: @dotNET, I left the team several years ago, but I'll pass on your feedback about wanting more visibility into what's next, as well as the implied question about the proper feedback channel.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft: Thanks a bunch. Really appreciate that. It isn't just we can't see where we're headed. There are 3 big issues. Firstly, VSTO covered almost all of the Object Model and we had the freedom to write powerful add-ins. Microsoft decided not to move VSTO to .NET Core/.NET 5/6 and thus our only option forward is JS, which brings up the second issue. JS API is lame even at level 1.4 (which will only be supported by Office 2021, thus leaving all older users in the dust). Even basic things like Shapes collection are not supported. (continued...)

Comment: Lastly, different versions of Microsoft Office support different subsets of the API, which nullifies the very purpose of JS API i.e. being cross-platform. I understand that you are not part of the team anymore, but hope you can bring this into some relevant person's attention. I'm a long long time Office developer who has been doing VBA/VSTO for over 20 years. and now looking for my ways forward.

Comment: @dotNET, I just passed along all three of your comments. For your comment regarding VSTO, do you mean that add-ins developed and running against Office 2010/2013/2016 will not work with newer Office? That would surprise me, but like I said, I've moved teams several years back and haven't been keeping up with the latest developments (I was, however, a VSTO developer myself before coming to Microsoft)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft: Add-ins created with VSTO do work in Office 2019/2021 and most probably a couple of future versions too. What Microsoft did here is that they migrated most .NET Framework technologies to .NET 5/6 (WinForms, WPF, UWP, ASP.NET, EF), but excluded VSTO. So if you want to stick to VSTO, you can't use newer versions of .NET.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft: On the other hand, JS-based add-in appeal us because we can't target Office for Mac with VSTO, whereas JS-based add-ins are advertised to run on all versions of Office, which is practically false. JS Office APIs are still lacking on many fronts (e.g. Document.Shapes collection is still not supported by Word API).

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft: So all in all, if you go for VSTO, you can't target other platforms and if you go for JS, you find that the APIs are heavily lacking and can't be used to achieve what VSTO could achieve 5 years ago (or VBA could do 15 years ago).

Comment: @dotNET, I see what you mean now, thanks for the clarification. I’ve passed on your feedback and a link to this thread to a couple folks on the team, which is as much as I can do now that I’m several years removed from the platform. All the best!

Comment: Is this the replacement to the uservoice forum?
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/refresh-word-content-controls-when-linked-customxml-changes/idi-p/3597928

Comment: @MattFitzmaurice, I have moved away from the Office Platform team several years ago... but looking at the link, it certainly seems to be.